# Auto Custom Number Following Category Selected in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to generate custom number based on Category.
I have 2 category :

1. RED
2. BLUE

The format of number is **00001/RED/2023** if user selecting RED category, **00001/BLUE/2023** if selecting BLUE category. **00001** is increment. Do increment based on the selected Category.

| BLUE | RED |
| --- | --- |
| 00001/BLUE/2023 | 00001/RED/2023 |
| 00002/BLUE/2023 | 00002/RED/2023 |

Currently, i have code like this :

```
    $query = Table::select(DB::raw('LEFT(code_number,5) as conum'));
    $number = "";
    if ($query->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->get() as $q) {
            $data = ((int)$q->conum) + 1;
            $number = sprintf("%04s", $data);
        }
    } else {
        $number = "00001";
    }
    $codenumber = $number . "/BLUE/" . date('Y');
    return $codenumber;
```

How to implement that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that you're trying to generate unique code numbers based on categories either BLUE or RED. You'll need to separate the increments based on the category. So, when a new BLUE item is added, it should increment only the latest BLUE number, not the latest RED number, and vice versa.

Here's a suggestion on how you might modify your code:

```php
public function generateCodeNumber($category){
    $query = Table::where('code_number', 'like', "%/$category/%")->select(DB::raw('LEFT(code_number,5) as conum'));
    $number = "";
    if ($query->count() > 0) {
        $max_number = $query->orderBy('conum', 'desc')->first()->conum;
        $data = ((int)$max_number) + 1;
        $number = sprintf("%05s", $data);
    } else {
        $number = "00001";
    }
    $codenumber = $number . "/$category/" . date('Y');
    return $codenumber;
}
```

Usage:

```
$this->generateCodeNumber('BLUE');
$this->generateCodeNumber('RED');
```

Comment: wow thank you very much. yes, thats what i mean.